# prove that $a +b_1 +2 \leq 3 * (b_2 + 1)$ using the following inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

prove $$a +b_1 +2 \leq 3 * (b_2 + 1)$$

Here are your assumptions:

$$(a + 1) * 3 < b_1 + b_2 + 2$$

$$b_1 + 1 < (b_2 + 1 ) * 2$$

$$(a+1) * 3 \geq b_1 + b_2 + 1$$

$$(a + 1) \leq (b_1 + b_2 + 1 ) * 3$$

$$(b_1 + 1) * 3 \geq b_2 + 1$$

$$(b_1 + 1) \leq (b_2 + 1) * 3$$

I need to know if it's possible to prove it using these assumptions because I've been trying to work on this for over an hour and i'm getting nowhere. I had to develop these inequalities myself so I'm wondering if either my algebra is lacking or my inequalities are not enough.

Thanks.

Comment: These inequalities are enough: if we denote $z=a+1,\,x=b_1+1,\,y=b_2+1$ then [wolframalpha($3y-x-z<0$ & these assumptions)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FullSimplify[3*y-x-z%3C0+%26%26+3*z%3Cx%2By+%26%26+x%3C2*y+%26%26+3*z%3E%3Dx%2By-1+%26%26+z%3C%3D3*%28x%2By-1%29+%26%26+3*x%3E%3Dy+%26%26+x%3C%3Dy*3]) gives `False`.

Comment: If you've had a "discrete math" class, this problem can be solved by formulation as a "linear program".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=a+1,\,x=b_1+1,\,y=b_2+1$, then
$$\begin{cases}
3z<x+y\\x<2y
\end{cases}\Rightarrow 3z<3y \iff z<y$$
$$3y-x-z=\underbrace{(2y-x)}_{>0}+\underbrace{(y-z)}_{>0}>0\iff 3y>x+z,$$
and then we look back to what we need to prove...

Comment: so in other words the inequality is false?

Comment: Edited. We need to prove $z+x\le 3y$. :) Nope, it's true :)